# Whenever run "npm start" this error is showing. How to solve it?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

**Error:**

Failed to compile
./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prefix_exceptions' of undefined
at Array.map ()
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'prefix_exceptions' of undefined at Array.map ()` What error is trying to tell is you are accessing the property `prefix_exceptions` of `undefined`

Comment: Today I have started to experience this error, currently trying to figure it out. My guess is that it's problem in autoprefixer depencency.

Comment: Same problem too...

Comment: We are facing the same problem too Today! :(

Comment: has anyone been able to fix this?  I have tracked it down to possibly be from the autoprifixer lib which uses postcss package.  i have attempted to update all the postcss affiliated packages but there are so many.

Comment: in my project everything was packed in a package like `react-scripts` let's say, I fixed it by removing the `^` from all the dependencies in the package.json, I just locked the version of all of them, but don't know which one was responsible..maybe this can help anyway @TimSmart

Comment: In my case I get this error whenever I try to import css like import "./index.css";

Comment: Deleteing node_modules and re-installing  package solved m problem